# busybox crond avoids concurrent processes for first 10 minutes?

Tags: docker, cron, busybox

I have a script that's executed **every minute** by cron in an Alpine container. Said script may run for long time, which is why it handles locking itself.

Just now I noticed the busybox' `crond` avoids executing the script for the first 10 minutes of a long-running instance, only after that the expected schedule is resumed. Verified this behavior by logging from the script; also `crond: user abc: process already running: sync.sh` is logged by cron (see below) during said period when script is expected to be triggered.

**Why is this and where is the logic documented?**

---

```
$ crond --help
BusyBox v1.36.1 (2023-07-27 17:12:24 UTC) multi-call binary.

Usage: crond [-fbS] [-l N] [-d N] [-L LOGFILE] [-c DIR]

    -f  Foreground
    -b  Background (default)
    -S  Log to syslog (default)
    -l N    Set log level. Most verbose 0, default 8
    -d N    Set log level, log to stderr
    -L FILE Log to FILE
    -c DIR  Cron dir. Default:/var/spool/cron/crontabs
```

```
$ cat /etc/crontabs/abc 
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=""

# m h dom mon dow     command
# ============================================================================
*/1 * * * *  sync.sh
```

Cron is started in container with `/usr/sbin/crond -f -l 8 -L /dev/stdout -c /etc/crontabs`

```
#   from docker host:
$ docker logs  my-container
usermod: no changes
crond: crond (busybox 1.36.1) started, log level 8
crond: USER abc pid  27 cmd sync.sh
crond: user abc: process already running: sync.sh
crond: USER root pid 158 cmd run-parts /etc/periodic/15min
crond: user abc: process already running: sync.sh
crond: user abc: process already running: sync.sh
crond: user abc: process already running: sync.sh
crond: user abc: process already running: sync.sh
crond: user abc: process already running: sync.sh
crond: user abc: process already running: sync.sh
crond: user abc: process already running: sync.sh
crond: user abc: process already running: sync.sh

/ around here 10 minute mark is hit, and crond starts invoking sync.sh again /

crond: USER abc pid 193 cmd sync.sh
sendmail: can't connect to remote host (127.0.0.1): Connection refused
crond: USER abc pid 219 cmd sync.sh
sendmail: can't connect to remote host (127.0.0.1): Connection refused
crond: USER abc pid 245 cmd sync.sh
sendmail: can't connect to remote host (127.0.0.1): Connection refused
```

---

Stripped down reproduction of said script:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#####################################
readonly SELF="${0##*/}"
DIR="$(cd -- "$(dirname -- "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" && pwd)"
JOB_ID="test-$$"
LOG="/config/${SELF}.log"

STATE_FILE=/tmp/test.state
#####################################

_prepare_locking()  { eval "exec 9>\"/tmp/test.lock\""; }
exlock_now()             { flock -xn 9; }

_log() {
    local lvl msg
    readonly lvl="$1"
    readonly msg="$2"
    echo -e "[$(date '+%F %T')] [$JOB_ID]\t$lvl  $msg" | tee -a "$LOG" >&2
    return 0
}

info() {
    _log INFO "$*"
}


update_statefile() {
    local time time_d

    _write_state() {
        echo -n "$time" > "$STATE_FILE"
    }

    time="$(date +%s)"

    if [[ -s "$STATE_FILE" ]]; then
        time_d="$((time - $(cat -- "$STATE_FILE")))"

        if [[ "$time_d" -ge 600 ]]; then
            info "$SELF has been running for at least ${time_d}s..."
            exit 1
        fi
    else
        _write_state
    fi

    info 'unable to obtain lock, process is already running'
    exit 0  # exit, not return
}


#### ENTRY ####
_prepare_locking || exit 1
exlock_now || update_statefile
info "$SELF starting up..."
sleep 20m  # block

exit 0
```

---

**Edit:**
So far can only conclude it's some busybox' cron oddity -- [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10503433/should-linux-cron-jobs-be-specified-with-an-to-indicate-to-run-in-background#comment133031619_10503463) in a related thread seems to confirm it.

Explicitly backgrounding the process in crontab using `&` makes this phenomenon disappear. Downside to this however is that killing the process group via `kill -- -pid` no longer works:

```bash
container-hostname:/# ps -ef | grep sync.sh
   34 abc       0:00 bash /usr/local/sbin/sync.sh
 1633 root      0:00 grep sync.sh
container-hostname:/# kill -9 -- -34
bash: kill: (-34) - No such process
```

Comment: This more likely is caused by your script, about which we know nothing.

Comment: @harrymc fair enough. Added sample script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered this after much hair-pulling. It appears to be intentional and specific to busybox cron based on [a comment](https://github.com/mirror/busybox/commit/69d69e2cb898f77827d2cf2c06a7f6fcd5157567#diff-8d5c4dde9f828c181630515f72b42c3fa465a2d22e47e43d659155ca00a9f577R314-R315) in the source.

I believe [this](https://github.com/mirror/busybox/blob/2d4a3d9e6c1493a9520b907e07a41aca90cdfd94/miscutils/crond.c#L917) may be where the logic is actually implemented. Looks like it has always been this way so doubt it will ever be changed.